# Can I use AWS CLI to create an RDS data-source in Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-quicksight

I want to create a data source connecting to one of our RDS instances. I can easily create a data source to RDS through the UI but when I use AWS CLI, I only see these values as possible values for `create-data-source` command:

`ADOBE_ANALYTICS AMAZON_ELASTICSEARCH ATHENA AURORA AURORA_POSTGRESQL AWS_IOT_ANALYTICS GITHUB JIRA MARIADB MYSQL POSTGRESQL PRESTO REDSHIFT S3 SALESFORCE SERVICENOW SNOWFLAKE SPARK SQLSERVER TERADATA TWITTER`

But I do see `RdsParameters` in the options:

[image]

What am I missing? How can I create a data-source connecting to an RDS instance

Answer (score 1):

Use the RDS database which is listed in the values.

```
aws quicksight create-data-source --aws-account-id 1234567890 --data-source-id "abcdefghijkl" --name "NameOfDS" --type POSTGRESQL --data-source-parameters ...
```

The above is for a PostGreSQL DB, which is created in RDS.

The alternate is to create a JSON file with all the required parameters and then use a command like the below

```
aws quicksight create-data-source --cli-input-json file://./create-data-source-cli-input.json
```

Output for which will be:

```
{
    "Status": 202,
    "Arn": "arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:datasource/sample-postgres-db",
    "DataSourceId": "sample-postgres-db",
    "CreationStatus": "CREATION_IN_PROGRESS",
    "RequestId": "d4392bc6-77fa-4346-8e9c-09a716761c4b"
}
```

The format of the JSON file will be:

```
{
    "AwsAccountId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "DataSourceId": "sample-postgres-db",
    "Name": "sample-postgres-db",
    "Type": "POSTGRESQL",
    "DataSourceParameters": {
        "PostgreSqlParameters": {
            "Host": "hostname.from-rds.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
            "Port": 5432,
            "Database": "name-of-db"
        }
    },
    "Credentials": {
        "CredentialPair": {
            "Username": "xxxxxxxxxxxx_postgres_admin",
            "Password": "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    "Permissions": [
        {
            "Principal": "arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/default/alice",
            "Actions": [
                "quicksight:UpdateDataSourcePermissions",
                "quicksight:DescribeDataSource",
                "quicksight:DescribeDataSourcePermissions",
                "quicksight:PassDataSource",
                "quicksight:UpdateDataSource",
                "quicksight:DeleteDataSource"
                
            ]
        }
    ],
    "VpcConnectionProperties": {
        "VpcConnectionArn": "arn:aws:quicksight:ap-southeast-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:vpcConnection/QuickSight-DB-VPC"
    },
    "Tags": [
        {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "PGSQL-TestDB"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: the data-source-id is a value I can set as I please or is it supposed to be the Id of an existing data-source?

Comment: You can set it to whatever name you want it to be in this. You are creating the datasource here, so it's ID can be set by you. If you use an existing one, then you need the UUID created by QS

Comment: I was able to create datasource but issue while creating dataset. it says I don't have access to create dataset with arn.

Comment: You need to add your User to the Group to enable users

Comment: @gagneet : is it possible to pass input json and db credentials separately while creating data source? I don't want to put db user/password within json. I tried this but its not working:

```aws quicksight create-data-source --Credentials={CredentialPair={Username=user,Password=Pwd}} --cli-input-json file://./create-data-source.json```

Note: I am getting that username/pwd from vault just above this aws cli command, so I can't put those in json, looking for a way to use those credentials on the fly, to avoid any credentials exposure

Comment: @gagneet or if you can provide the whole command to create rds data source without using json, I am not sure how to pass credentials block within aws cli command and also other blocks like Permissions, DataSourceParameters etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is your RDS database MARIADB MYSQL POSTGRESQL or AURORA?
Then I will assume you have to add the RDS parameters regardless of engine.